# Elegant Way to Control Visibility of Top-Level Components as User Moves Through React Application?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I can imagine factoring a React UI into a set of top-level components, only one of which is visible at a given time based on the state of the application. There might be a different component for each step in a wizard, for example. Or components representing different forms that take different sets of information. You want only one of these to be visible at any given time.

What's the most elegant way of expressing which component should be visible based on the current state of the application? I'm thinking that you'd want to express this using the outermost App component (that is just inside Provider) in some way.

Comment: Adding a router might be a good place to start?

Comment: How do you handle form submissions with such an approach, so that the action attribute directs the user just within the client to the next component but still submits the information?

Comment: yes. If it is a SPA approach you are looking for, that would be how to handle it. After submit is done, redirect to the next route.

Comment: Are you saying you'd allow a full  form submit entailing a post-back to the browser and a full-reload of the app? Or do you handle the onclick event of the submit button and use JSON or something? In other words, how do you do the post without doing a reload?

Comment: no. You use something like apisauce or similar to handle your api rest calls. Await the result and keep going.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand: use the form onsubmit handler to make an API rest call and await the result. then use the browserhistory object to navigate, client-side without a server call, to the next piece of UI? The router object has mapped the argument browserhistory receives to the appropriate UI component?

Comment: have a look at react-router ex.its probably plenty of tutorials out there on how to handle form-submits in "single page applications"

Comment: Or maybe I could ask someone on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Most of this is pretty available just googling. Expecting everyone else to do your work is not the way to go.

Comment: I'm not expecting everyone else to do my work. I'm just expecting those who have the knowledge and choose to provide answers to do so thoroughly instead of dropping a crumb and then quickly diverting and telling me to Google it or do a tutorial. If you don't like it, stop leaving partial, evasive answers for which you're not going to get credit.